# Filter returns first element of array instead of

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am implementing a hash map for the Two Sum [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) problem.

```
const testArrs = {
    'first': [2,7,11,15],
    'second': [3,2,4],
    'third': [3,3]
}

function twoSum(nums, target) {
    let mapped = nums.map((item) => target - item);
    let returnedArr = mapped.filter((item) => {
        if (nums.includes(item)) {
            console.log(nums.indexOf(target-item))
            return nums.indexOf(target - item)
        }
    })

    console.log(returnedArr)
    //TODO check if returnedArr size == 2.

}

twoSum(testArrs['first'], 9)
```

The first array *mapped* creates an array of hashes as "indexes" that are the difference of target from each element in the *nums* array. Then I apply a filter to the mapped array to see if 2 elements of the mapped array are contained in the nums array, returning the index of those elements.

When the indexes are filtered into the *returnedArr* it seems to return the first element of nums instead of two indexes. **[2] instead of [0,1]** The logging before the return shows it is correctly registering indexes 0 and 1 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because youre mixing the filter with the the map function. The map function must return a boolean (which will create an array of the targets which comply with the condition). And, after getting those values, in your case, the ones that are contained in the nums, you map them to get their index.
Like this:

```
const testArrs = {
    'first': [2,7,11,15],
    'second': [3,2,4],
    'third': [3,3]
}

function twoSum(nums, target) {
    let mapped = nums.map((item) => target - item);
    let returnedArr = mapped.filter((item) => {
        return nums.includes(item)
    })
    return returnedArr.map((item)=> nums.indexOf(target-item))

}

console.log(twoSum(testArrs['first'], 9))`
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `return nums.indexOf(target - item)` results to `false` if the `index` is `0`. Instead, you need to check if `nums.indexOf(target - item) >= 0`.

However, [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) isn't really what you're looking for:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Instead, you need to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to save the number-index pairs, and then check if a complement is in the Map:

```js
function twoSum(nums, target) {
  const map = new Map();
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    map.set(nums[i], i);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    const complement = target - nums[i];
    if (map.has(complement) && map.get(complement) != i) {
      return [i, map.get(complement)];
    }
  }
}

const testArrs = { 'first': [2,7,11,15], 'second': [3,2,4], 'third': [3,3] };
console.log( twoSum(testArrs['first'], 9) );
```

A faster way would be doing it in one iteration:

```js
function twoSum(nums, target) {
  const map = new Map();
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    const complement = target - nums[i];
    if (map.has(complement)) {
      return [map.get(complement), i];
    }
    map.set(nums[i], i);
  }
}

const testArrs = { 'first': [2,7,11,15], 'second': [3,2,4], 'third': [3,3] };
console.log( twoSum(testArrs['first'], 9) );
```

Comment: Interesting, where is there documentation about returning negative if the index is 0? Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy